# Can I submit the same .xap to Windows Phone store with the two developer ID's?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mobile-application, windows-phone-store

I have already submitted the Windows Phone 8 app to the windows phone store. Got new requirement to submit the same .xap with the same name to the app store with different Developer ID. How can I do that? We want both the apps to be present. Also is it possible that existing users can upgrade the app after it is submitted by new Developer ID? can we notify users by giving new link for the app from another developer ID(If it's possible to put another app using new developer ID)?

Comment: Not related to worklight, removing tag. You can use the worklight console to send a one-time notification to all app users - consult with the IBM knowledge center about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to submit the app with the same name even you are using a new Developer ID since you have to associate your app with the store, where the `App Name` should be unique. Yes you can push an update for the existing app by selecting `Update App` from the `Dev Center`.

[Reserving a name for your app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642078(v=vs.105).aspx)

[Updating your app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj631569(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: So how can I manage above scenario in case of app re-branding? And can same .xap be submitted with two different reserved App Names; means app name is associated with the store and not xap?

Comment: yes that's possible, but why you wanna submit the same app in two different names?

Comment: We are going to do re-branding.

Comment: Kulasangar, but if we are submitting same xap using another publisher ID, we have to change Publisher name and Product ID and Publisher ID as well, right?

Comment: yeah, it'll automatically take those details when u associate your app in VS.